# Batch download URLs in PHP?

Tags: php

So, I have a PHP script that is supposed to download images that the user inputs. However, if the user uploads a TXT file and it contains direct links to images, it should download the images from all the URLs in the file. My script seems to be working, although it seems that only the last file is downloaded while the others are stored as files containing no data.

Here's the portion of my script where it parses the TXT

```
$contents = file($file_tmp);
$parts = new SplFileObject($file_tmp);
foreach($parts as $line) {
   $url = $line;
   $dir = "{$save_loc}".basename($url);
   $fp = fopen ($destination, 'w+');
   $raw = file_get_contents($url);
   file_put_contents($dir, $raw);
}
```

How do I make it download every URL from the TXT file?

Comment: Show us the input file or at least some of it as an example, unless all you want are **guesses**

Comment: @RiggsFolly the input file is a weird picture of a skunk someone drew for me. I'll add it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over an `SplFileObject`, you get the whole line, including whitespace. Your URL will thus be something like

```
http://example.com/_
```

(php seems to mangle the newline to an underscore) and thus you'll get an error for many URLs (some URLs will still work fine, since they contain the important information prior. For instance, [Batch download URLs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970529/batch-download-urls-in-php_) works, but https://stackoverflow.com/_ does not). If an error occurs, `file_get_contents` will return `false`, and `file_put_contents` will interpret that like an empty string.

Also, the line `$fp = fopen ($destination, 'w+');` is really strange. For one, since `$destination` is not defined, it would error anyways. Even if `$destination` is defined, you'll end up with lots of file handles and overwrite that poor file multiple times. You can just remove it.

To summarize, your code should look like

```
<?php
$file_tmp = "urls.txt";
$save_loc = "sav/";

$parts = new SplFileObject($file_tmp);
foreach($parts as $line) {
    $url = trim($line);
    if (!$url) {
        continue;
    }
    $dir = "{$save_loc}".basename($url);
    $raw = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($raw === false) {
        echo 'failed to donwload ' . $url . "\n";
        continue;
    }
    file_put_contents($dir, $raw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like line

```
$parts = new SplFileObject($file_tmp);
```

isn't necessary as well as

```
$fp = fopen ($destination, 'w+');
```

`file()` function reads entire file into array. You just have call `trim()` on each array element to remove new line from characters. Following code should work properly:

```
<?php
$save_loc = './';
$urls = file('input.txt');
foreach($urls as $url) {
  $url = trim($url);
  $destination = $save_loc . basename($url);
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  if ($content) {
    file_put_contents($destination, $content);
  }
}
```